# MySQL bulk query update in a single query using multiple criterias

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, bulk

This looks like a common question among many but I am yet to find a solution that helps.

I have been able to find a bulk insert query that requires only a single query but for update, the structure of the query is a fair bit different.

Is it possible to create an update query that works with many different lines.

I am already able to create a query that runs the correct number of times and updates the rows correctly but it runs multiple times.

This creates quite a stack of queries which as everyone knows, can take alot of processing.

Here is the bulk insert query I have found:

```
$sql = array();  
foreach( $data as $row ) {     
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['text']).'", '.$row['category_id'].')'; 
    } 
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (text, category) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with an update query. You'll have to make one query per update.

Unless ofcourse you want to update based on a field like:
`UPDATE TABLE SET field_1=1 WHERE field_2=2`

Comment: Saying that, what about an UPDATE builder? something like mysql_query($update1 . $update2 . $update3) but obviously made more elegant?

Comment: It all depends on what you really want (and why). You could do a REPLACE INTO, or INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY. But without knowing what you want and why its difficult to say anything. I'm not sure what $update1 $update2 should be?

Comment: im attempting to program this into my script to test it at the mo, example:    for($x=0;$x<sizeof($title);$x++){
    $sql[] = "UPDATE menu SET title='".$title[$x]."', path='".$path[$x]."', section='".$section[$x]."'";
   }
   mysql_query(implode(';', $sql));

Comment: You could do that but you need to use mysqli_multi_query (note that this is mysqli)

Comment: so then that would be the answer to my question i assume?

Comment: No, the first answer is the answer to your question. The multiquery is just sending multiple queries at once (which makes sql injection easier!)